# Scala error Spark Streaming Kafka : ambiguous reference to overloaded definition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to create kafka direct stream with supplying offsets externally within my Spark streaming module, however it results into below compilation error.

Here is the code to create Kafka direct stream

```
val kafkaParams = Map("metadata.broker.list" -> "kafka.brokers")
// testing only
val fromOffsets: Map[TopicPartition, Long] = Map[TopicPartition, Long]()

val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[Array[Byte], Array[Byte], DefaultDecoder, DefaultDecoder, Array[Byte]]
    (ssc, kafkaParams, fromOffsets, (mmd: MessageAndMetadata[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]]) => mmd.message())
```

Here is the compilation error I'm running into. Any ideas/pointers ?

```
    ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method createDirectStream in object KafkaUtils of type (jssc: org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext, keyClass: Class[Array[Byte]], valueClass: Class[Array[Byte]], keyDecoderClass: Class[kafka.serializer.DefaultDecoder], valueDecoderClass: Class[kafka.serializer.DefaultDecoder], recordClass: Class[Array[Byte]], kafkaParams: java.util.Map[String,String], fromOffsets: java.util.Map[kafka.common.TopicAndPartition,Long], messageHandler: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function[kafka.message.MessageAndMetadata[Array[Byte],Array[Byte]],Array[Byte]])org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaInputDStream[Array[Byte]]
and  method createDirectStream in object KafkaUtils of type (ssc: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext, kafkaParams: Map[String,String], fromOffsets: Map[kafka.common.TopicAndPartition,Long], messageHandler: kafka.message.MessageAndMetadata[Array[Byte],Array[Byte]] => Array[Byte])(implicit evidence$14: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Array[Byte]], implicit evidence$15: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Array[Byte]], implicit evidence$16: scala.reflect.ClassTag[kafka.serializer.DefaultDecoder], implicit evidence$17: scala.reflect.ClassTag[kafka.serializer.DefaultDecoder], implicit evidence$18: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Array[Byte]])org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream[Array[Byte]]
match expected type ?
[ERROR]     val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[Array[Byte], Array[Byte], DefaultDecoder, DefaultDecoder, Array[Byte]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `kafka.common.TopicAndPartition` instead of `org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition`.

Comment: Great! That fixed this mysterious error. Thanks for the quick reply. Too much  intelligence on the scala compiler to not to turn this into a more simpler error message.